# Why is uncaught error:$ not defined anonyomus function showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've looked at all the similar posts regarding Uncaught error: $is not defined and nothing has helped. I have the latest jquery library and just not understanding why this error is showing.

```
$(function() {

    // Checking for CSS 3D transformation support
    $.support.css3d = supportsCSS3D();

    var formContainer = $('#formContainer');

    $('.flipLink').click(function(e){

        // Flipping the forms
        formContainer.toggleClass('flipped');

        if(!$.support.css3d){
            $('#login').toggle();
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    formContainer.find('form').submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    function supportsCSS3D() {
        var props = [
            'perspectiveProperty', 'WebkitPerspective', 'MozPerspective'
        ], testDom = document.createElement('a');

        for(var i=0; i<props.length; i++){
            if(props[i] in testDom.style){
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

I'm calling the script here as scripts.js

```
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href= "css/styles.css">


    </head>
```

I would very appreciative to get the knowledge to understand why this happened in this situation and any tips as well.

Comment: Make sure the jQuery header is above the code in which you use it. Are you are the jQuery path file you are using is correct?

Comment: $ is not defined = jQuery is not loaded

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. Now I know what it means moving forward @Pekka

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include your script **after** jQuery, not before.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Browsers evaluate `<script>` tag contents as soon as they're loaded, incrementally.  If you put yours first, the browser will attempt to run it before even parsing the subsequent scripts.  Thus, your script's dependencies won't be satisfied and you'll get errors like that.

Answer (score 3):

You should load your scripts.js after the jquery scripts:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href= "css/styles.css">
</head>
```

Comment: As for why: scripts are loaded in the order their <script src=""> elements are defined in your HTML document. If you have a large number of inter-dependent scripts, maintaining the correct load order can become an issue. That's where script loaders such as RequireJS step in: http://requirejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the script tags for jquery above your scripts.js so $ is defined.